# How sed 's/pattern/substitution/2g' really work?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Why  `echo 'word word word word word word' | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]* /DELETED /2g'`

prints `word DELETED DELETED DELETED DELETED word` ?

Why **sed** didn't substitute the last `word` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your regular expression has a trailing space:

```
/[a-zA-Z]* /
          ^
```

It's explicitly searching for zero or more letters followed by a space.

Comment: well, my experience says, typos and stray `;`, ` ` are the most difficult to find out in your own script.